# Binary file showing as modified after git checkout

Tags: windows, git

For some reason, after cloning a repository and changing branch I had one `jar` file marked as modified (without being modified) and I can't seem to un-modify the file (which prevents merging branches.

```
PS D:\src\expm> git status
On branch epic-my-wallet
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature-01'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Test/Selenium/selenese-runner.jar

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I tried to undo with the checkout command

```
PS D:\src\expm> git checkout -- .
```

`git status` output the same exact message as previously.

I tried to reset it from `HEAD` with

```
PS D:\src\expm> git checkout -f HEAD
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature-01'.
```

Please note that jar files are flagged as handled by LFS in the `.gitattributes` file

```
*.jar filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Not quite sure on the next step here. The file has not been modified since its commit months ago.

**edit**
I should add that today we tried to reset the cache with `git rm . -r --cached` and removed the LFS cache as well (physically remove the `.git/lfs` folder) and re-download the files with `git reset --hard`.

Comment: Did you try git checkout -- Test/Selenium/selenese-runner.jar

Comment: I indeed did with the same exact result as the `git checkout -- .`. We even did a hard reset with `git reset --hard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem the problem was linked to Git LFS in some way. We upgraded both Git (from 2.8.4 to the current at 2.9.3) and Git LFS (from 1.2.1 locally to the latest 1.3.1 at the moment). Then deleted and re-added the jar file.

We did a clean clone on a new folder after that and the problem seemed to be resolved. Could be the upgrade of git + lfs that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Due to your git setting to handle end of line, which should be to 'autocrlf', git modify/corrupt the jar file at checkout!

You should add a '.gitattributes' file in your repository where you set the 'jar' files as 'binary' and git will no more try to convert end of lines.

That's the recommended way to handle end of line in a git repository to solve such problems...

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the jar file is a binary, should not be influenced by autcrlf, and indeed was not.